# Retrieve min and max time from same table in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table that have sigh in and  sign out value

```
**id   Date     Time   Status**
  01   1/02/12  8:10   Entry
  01   1/02/12  9:00   Exit
  01   1/02/12  9:10   entry
  01   1/02/12  17:00  Exit
  02   1/02/12  8:10   Entry
  02   1/02/12  9:00   Exit
  02   1/02/12  9:10   entry
  02   1/02/12  17:00  Exit
  **03   1/02/12  17:00  Exit**
```

I have to find out only min and max time of each id

Expected result

```
**id   Date     Entry     Exit  **
  01   1/02/12  8:10      17:00
  02   1/02/12  8:10      17:00
```

Please Help me

This code Works fine But incase one Entry is not added only exit is added then
i Want to display

```
id   Date     Entry Exit
---- -------- ----- -----
01   01/02/12 08:10 17:00
02   01/02/12 08:10 17:00
**03   01/02/12 Null  17:00**
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the datatypes for your columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work depending on data types used.

```
declare @T table
(
  id varchar(2),
  [Date] datetime,
  [Time] varchar(5),
  [Status] varchar(5)
)

insert into @T
select '01',   '1/02/12',  '8:10',   'Entry' union all
select '01',   '1/02/12',  '9:00',   'Exit' union all
select '01',   '1/02/12',  '9:10',   'entry' union all
select '01',   '1/02/12',  '17:00',  'Exit' union all
select '02',   '1/02/12',  '8:10',   'Entry' union all
select '02',   '1/02/12',  '9:00',   'Exit' union all
select '02',   '1/02/12',  '9:10',   'entry' union all
select '02',   '1/02/12',  '17:00',  'Exit'

select id,
       convert(varchar(8), [Date], 1) as [Date],
       convert(varchar(5), min([Time]), 108) as [Entry],
       convert(varchar(5), max([Time]), 108) as [Exit]
from
  (
    select id,
           [Date],
           cast([Time] as datetime) as [Time],
           row_number() over(partition by id order by [Date]+cast([Time] as datetime) asc) as rn1,
           row_number() over(partition by id order by [Date]+cast([Time] as datetime) desc) as rn2
    from @T
  ) as T
where T.rn1 = 1 or
      T.rn2 = 1
group by id, [Date]
```

Result:

```
id   Date     Entry Exit
---- -------- ----- -----
01   01/02/12 08:10 17:00
02   01/02/12 08:10 17:00
```

Comment: @kknaufal - Good to hear. Then you should consider accepting the answer as the correct one using the check mark to the left. It will signal to the community that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Write a query like below

```
Select * from MyTable where Time = (Select min(Time) from MyTable) and Status = 'Entry'
```

and

```
Select * from MyTable where Time = (Select max(Time) from MyTable) and Status = 'Exit'
```

EDIT:

If you want a single query to the values like that you can get it as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyTable.ID, MyTable.Date, MyTable.Time AS Entry, MyTable_2.Time AS
[Exit] FROM MyTable CROSS JOIN MyTable AS MyTable_2 WHERE (MyTable.Time =
(SELECT MIN(Time) AS Expr1 FROM MyTable AS MyTable_1)) AND (MyTable.Status = 'Entry') 
AND (MyTable_2.Time = (SELECT MAX(Time) AS Expr2 FROM MyTable AS MyTable_3)) AND 
(MyTable_2.Status = 'Exit')
```